# How do you return selected columns along with COUNT(*) in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Edit: Thank you Tim Biegeleisen for pointing out a typo in my question.
I had 50 in both limit and offset in my actual code, so I haven't noticed until you pointed it out.

I am trying to limit the rows that are returned from my query, but still keep the total count of rows in the table.

I have attempted the following:

```
SELECT 
    first,
    last_name,
    date_joined,
    age,
    COUNT(*) AS num_people
FROM
    foo_table
WHERE
    city = 'bar'
ORDER BY date_joined DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

However, this only returns a single row, a seemingly arbitrary one at that. Changing it to

```
5 AS num_people
```

Correctly returns everything and simply implements a 5 in a seperate column **num_people**.
Why does this break when I attempt to use **COUNT(*)**?
Is there a better alternative to return both the total count as well as the selected rows?

Comment: Each SQL `SELECT` query can only return a single result table. So you will need to put  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo_table` as a separate query, but you should be able to execute statement-batches so only a single SQL batch will be sent to MySQL. What library (and programming language) are you using to execute SQL queries, exactly?

Comment: @Dai The query is sent from a PHP file, fetched by JavaScript. However, I barely have any experience in PHP.

Comment: Are you aware that `LIMIT 50 , 0` means `LIMIT 0 OFFSET 50` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for pointing it out. I had 50 in both offset and limit in my real code, so I haven't noticed before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 8+, and your requirement is to return a total row count along with the result set, you may consider using `COUNT()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT first, last_name, date_joined, age, COUNT(*) OVER () AS num_people
FROM foo_table
WHERE city = 'bar'
ORDER BY date_joined DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I'm using version 5.7, so this didn't work for me. However, it lead me to this MySQL forum post: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,517893,518029
I will edit my question to have the solution provided in there, but since the only reason this didn't work was a version difference, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @LeCarbonator ... if you are calling from something like PHP or Java, then there should be some result set metadata object which would also contain the size of the entire result set.